# Intellij and Maven provided scope

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

I need to define my dependencies with `provided` scope but I also need my applications to be able to run and tested within Intellij. How can I setup my workflow so that I can download all of the dependencies for Intellij to use for both auto-complete and being able to run them?

Answer (score 1):

Updated 2018/4/24: The IntelliJ idea 2018.1 has the option of "Include dependencies with Provided scope" in the run dialogue. So great!

Original Answer: 
The simple "hacking" way I know is go to the corresponding .iml file, replace all `scope="PROVIDED"` by empty string, and save the file.

However, the provided scope may come back, from refreshing pom.xml. Just need to redo the replacing.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of materials on the internet about intellij and dependency management with maven. [setting up spark with maven](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html) is an example of that.

I would suggest you to go with sbt for dependency management as it has improved and optimized techniques that maven build tool. [Apache Spark Scala Library Development with Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/12/12/apache-spark-scala-library-development-with-databricks.html) and [data scientist in training](http://data-scientist-in-training.blogspot.com/2015/02/getting-started-with-spark-kitchen-sink.html) should give a good start with that.

Moreover you can always search for maven provided scope in [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/)

You should be good to start a new project with intellij and maven provided scope with this information.